# No more RSS autodetect in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, rss

I'm creating an RSS feed out of some articles using CakePHP, but it doesn't show up in Firefox like it used to.

To be more precise: there used to be an RSS icon in the addressbar, but now it's not there.
Is adding this to the head element not enough?

```
<link href="http://domain.be/index.rss" type="application/rss+xml" rel="alternate" title="News">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link element seems reasonable, however note that Firefox 4 removed the RSS icon from the URL bar. Sorry, but I can't remember what they did with it; however for testing purposes you could try using SeaMonkey which still has an RSS icon in its URL bar.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Strange decision, but now I know it's not my markup's problem.

Comment: @skerit It turned out most users didn't understand it and didn't use it.  It can be added buck via the toolbar customization dialog.